# Move to next Control when Tab key is pressed

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a windows application containg diffrent controls like label,textbox,button..
And I need to select next Control when tab is pressed.

I am able to catch tab pressed event as:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Tab)
    {

    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

How shouid I procced further?

Comment: The Tab key already does that. Why interfere?

Comment: You realise that this is built in to Windows Forms? All you have to do is set the TabIndex to your preferred order (i.e. a textbox may have a TabIndex of 5 and button next to it could have a TabIndex of 6).

Comment: This is the natural flow, why is this not working in your case ?

Comment: if the controls are added randomly,The flow does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is handled for you automatically by the OS and you shouldn't interfere with it without a really good reason.

You can adjust the order of which control [Tab] goes to next by setting the `TabIndex` property for the controls that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you set it in the ***Tab Order***? this is Located in the Menu Bar of the visual studio.

```
Click first on the form => View = > Tab Order
```